# How to check if image is loaded from url [react-native]

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

The idea is to check if image is loaded from a url , if no i will show another image instead

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet , ImageBackground , Image} from 'react-native'

   const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true); //where to can handle it ?

    const ImageLoader = (props)=>{
        return (
            <ImageBackground  source={{uri: props.link}}  resizeMode = "cover">
                <Text> Title </Text>
                </ImageBackground>
        )
    }
```

I Know that the first step is to create a state, but where i can handle it ?

Answer (score 2):

In React Native, both the `<Image/>` and the `<ImageBackground/>` components can be passed the onLoad prop, which accepts a function. You may do something like this...

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Text, ImageBackground } from 'react-native'

const CustomImageComponent = (props) => {

     const { incomingImageLink } = props
     const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
     const defaultImageLink = "https://as2.ftcdn.net/v2/jpg/03/49/49/79/1000_F_349497933_Ly4im8BDmHLaLzgyKg2f2yZOvJjBtlw5.jpg"

     const onImageLoaded = () => {
          setLoading(false)
          console.log("do other stuff here if you want")
     }

     return (
         <ImageBackground
              onLoad={onImageLoaded}
              source={{uri: isLoading ? defaultImageLink : incomingImageLink}}
              resizeMode={"cover"}
         >
              <Text>
                 {isLoading ? "LOADING..." : "SUCCESSFULLY LOADED!"}
              </Text>
         </ImageBackground>
       )
}
```

For more information, here are some [docs for onLoad](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#onload).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by using onload and onerror events of js on img tags.
For more info, head to this [link](https://javascript.info/onload-onerror).

Comment: you mean i should add onload inside the jSX Image tag ? <ImageBackground  onload > ?

Comment: Yes u can write like <ImageBackground onLoad={() => handleOnLoad()} /> And write the logic in handleOnLoad method and same for onError